# Quick way to access first element in Numpy array with arbitrary number of dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that I want to have quickly access the first (aka zeroth) element of a given Numpy array, which itself might have any number of dimensions.  What's the quickest way to do that?

I'm currently using the following:

```
a.reshape(-1)[0]
```

This reshapes the perhaps-multi-dimensionsal array into a 1D array and grabs the zeroth element, which is short, sweet and often fast.  However, I think this would work poorly with some arrays, e.g., an array that is a transposed view of a large array, as I worry this would end up needing to create a copy rather than just another view of the  original array, in order to get everything in the right order.  (Is that right?  Or am I worrying needlessly?)  Regardless, it feels like this is doing more work than what I really need, so I imagine some of you may know a generally faster way of doing this?

Other options I've considered are creating an iterator over the whole array and drawing just one element from it, or creating a vector of zeroes containing one zero for each dimension and using that to fancy-index into the array.  But neither of these seems all that great either.

Comment: *"Or am I worrying needlessly?"*  No, you are not worrying needlessly!  Depending on the layout of `a`'s memory, `a.reshape(-1)` could result in a copy, which is certainly overkill when all you care about is the first element.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
a.flat[0]
```

This should be pretty fast and never require a copy. (Note that `a.flat` is an instance of [`numpy.flatiter`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatiter.html), not an array, which is why this operation can be done without a copy.)

Answer (score 15):

You can use `a.item(0)`; see the documentation at [`numpy.ndarray.item`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html).

A possible disadvantage of this approach is that the return value is a *Python* data type, not a numpy object.  For example, if `a` has data type `numpy.uint8`, `a.item(0)` will be a Python integer.  If that is a problem, `a.flat[0]` is better--see @user2357112's answer.

Comment: This is also a possible advantage, depending on what you're planning to do with the element.

Answer (score -2):

```
np.hsplit(x, 2)[0]
```

Source: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dsplit.html
Source:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html

Comment: This gives the first half of the array along the second axis, not the first element of the flattened array.

Answer (score -3):

```
## y -- numpy array of shape (1, Ty)
```

if you want to get the first element:

use `y.shape[0]`

if you want to get the second element:

use   `y.shape[1]`

Source: 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html

You can also use the take for more complicated extraction (to get few elements):

> numpy.take(a, indices, axis=None, out=None, mode='raise')[source] Take
>   elements from an array along an axis.